# Levenberg-Marquardt optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, newtons-method, levenberg-marquardt

Anyone knows where I cand find  an .m  (matlab ) file with the Levenberg-Marquardt  moditication to the Newton's method to optimize a function?

Thanks

Comment: Did you search at the [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)?

Answer (score 3):

I always start with a search on [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). Found a [LMF nonlinear solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17534-lmfnlsq-solution-of-nonlinear-least-squares). It also seems that there is a lsqnonlin function in The [optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html).  Of course that costs a small fortune and limits the portability of your code (one of many reasons I use Python these days).

Comment: Thank you ;) , This is my problem. The next point is x'=x+d , the displacement d is solved from the linear set of equation Hd=-gradf

Comment: Thank you ;) , Here is my problem. the next point is x'=x+d , the displacement d is solved from the linear set of equation Hd=-gradf , (H is the Hessian) , but there is a problem, What happend if the Hessian<0 , the point x'  can't work , because f(x')>f(x) and i'm triying to minimize the function intead maximize.  Therefero I think I should use the Levenberg-Marquardt method to stabilize the routine. I think I should compute the eigenvalues  of the  Hessian  (e.g. E=eig(H) ) And solve (H +a diag(E))d= -grad f ,Perhaps should i replace diag(E) by the unit matrix?, this is my code

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [MATLAB MEX version](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/~guuru/) of [CMPFIT](http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html), if that fits your purpose.

Comment: ^ this, or use .NET interop in Matlab on Windows and call CSMPFIT: https://csmpfit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try it here: http://people.cas.uab.edu/~mosya/cl/MATLABcircle.html

This is a web-page from proffesor Chernov, who published some papers and a book on the matter. There are also c and matlab sources.